# Can I have a live Ubuntu USB with a partition for persistent mode, AND have a partition that allows me to store windows files, on the same drive?

Tags: windows, partitioning, usb, live-usb

My question is, on one flash drive, can I have 3 partitions which are

1: The Live USB partitions (about 4GB)

2: Casper-rw partition of persistent mode (another 4GB)

^ those two are both created by the live USB program

3: A third partition which allows me to use the flash drive like a normal flash drive, for carrying windows files around. (the remaining 20` GB)

Is it possible to have both file systems on the drive, and if so, how do I make this?

The program I'm using for the live USB is [LiveLinux](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can store Windows files on the (Live), FAT32 partition, which should be the first partition.

Windows can only see the first partition on a Flash drive.

You can make the Fat32 partition as large as you like.

Edit 2017
**mkusb** will make such a drive with persistence and data partitions automatically.